# Use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items.Find with filter, that could contain quotation marks and apostrophes

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am having issues with the following filter.

```
string filter = String.Format(
   "[Start] = '{0}' AND [Subject] = '{1}' AND [BillingInformation] = 'Test'", 
   time.ToShortDateString() + " " + time.ToShortTimeString(), subject);
return items.Find(filter) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem;
```

I would like to be able to Find items, even if my subject contains both quotation marks and/or apostrophes. I tried it with:

```
string filter = string.Format(
   "[Start] = \"{0}\" AND [Subject] = \"{1}\" AND [BillingInformation] = \"Test\"", 
   string.Concat(time.ToShortDateString(), " ", time.ToShortTimeString()), 
   subject);
return items.Find(filter) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem;
```

Unfortunately, this will break my quotationmarks. And I am not even sure, if this will work with apostrophes now... It seems to work though.

How do I have to define the filter, so my subject both can use quotation marks and apostrophes?

Comment: What do you mean by "It seems to work though"? Is it producing the correct string including quotation marks, but not applying the filter correctly? Is it producing the wrong string, but performing the correct filtering?

Comment: The point is, that my half-working solution appears to be working for the apostrophes now, but not for the quotation marks anymore.

Comment: My quotation mark solution isnt working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of days trying to solve this:

This is the final solution, which works fine for me:

```
string filter = String.Format(
    "[Start] = '{0}' AND [Subject] = '{1}' AND [BillingInformation] = 'Test'", 
    time.ToShortDateString() + " " + time.ToShortTimeString(),
    subject.Replace("'", "''"));
return items.Find(filter) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem;
```

This will work fine. You have to use single quotation twice.

There was another small issue with non-breaking-spaces. When you add ror try to find appointments in outlook, make sure to not have any non-breaking-spaces. Remove them,, when adding or filtering items. Just my small advice for somebody with similar problems.